# How to encode in a better way?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to use the getdummies functionality for a large csv which is having 200000 rows and 24 columns.

I have converted the particular csv to a `pandas` dataframe.

The column name `company_products_services` contain string values just like the values that we encounter in a recommender system like genre.

While trying to encode I am getting memory error.

```
%%time
test_df=pd.concat([df_200K_1,df_200K_1['company_products_services'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')],axis=1)
test_df.shape
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please clarify: a) "memory error" you get - better as stack trace, b) sample of your data

Comment: I've had this issue before, we need to see a sample dataset to confirm.  But essentially there will be and new column fr every unique instance of a dummy variable.  So those 24 columns depending on there content can expand exponentially.  Back in my earlier days I've had 5 columns expand into 300-500 dummy variable columns.

Comment: how much sample dataset will do